# How do I parse HTTP text data representing a `Request` into a `net::http::Request` object?

Tags: rust

I have the following code that I run during a test setup:

```
fn setup_log_server() -> std::thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:10603").unwrap();

        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        }
    })
}
```

What this does is create a new thread that has a listener that listens on port 10603 of the `localhost`. The point of this is replicate a logging endpoint in my test code. Http requests are sent to it that look something like this:

```
POST /my/log HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:10603
User-Agent: reqwest/0.8.8
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 58
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"date":"2020-01-02 11:00:46 +06:00","text":"Hello World"}
```

This output was generated using the code:

```
let mut buffer = [0; 512];
let stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
```

I see a couple of problems with this (which I took from the documentation for creating a web server in the Rust Programming Language book):

First, the buffer is only 512 bytes. I don't know what happens if the request exceeds 512 bytes, but my gut tells me that the remainder of the request is simply dropped on the floor and discarded.

Secondly, I don't know exactly how to extract just the body of the request from this string of bytes.

What I'd like is to extract either a) just the body of the request, or, better yet, a `Request` object parsed from this input. I suppose I could go through writing a parser for http requests like in [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=dOlODwAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=rust+how+to+deserialize+http+request+from+stream+of+bytes&source=bl&ots=n0kZ72QWCS&sig=ACfU3U0x0tTadNm5nqsqX6nyDtuvfiAcOA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje7s2BwejmAhUTU80KHdFRAO0Q6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=rust%20how%20to%20deserialize%20http%20request%20from%20stream%20of%20bytes&f=false) but this seems like a lot of work for something that's likely already been done.

I also see that there is mention of deserializing from bytes in https://docs.rs/http/0.1.0/http/request/struct.Request.html but I'm not sure I understand what that means. I don't actually have a `Request<Vec<u8>>` as input, I have a `&[u8; 512]` (or I suppose I could convert this to a `Vec<u8>`.

Any thoughts on how I might approach this?

Comment: You are dealing with HTTP requests originated from a `reqwest` client. It has nothing to do with `reqwest` per se. You want a HTTP crate such as `actix-web` to write a HTTP server.

Comment: Well, it does have to do with `reqwest` in that the input is coming from a reqwest `RequestBuilder`, but I see what you mean about the question not having anything to do with `reqwest` directly. I'll edit the title. What I'd like is to parse from the http text blob to an `http::Request` (https://docs.rs/http/0.1.5/http/request/index.html) data structure. I'm wondering if such a parser already exists, or if it's something I simply have to write for myself.